# Best approach to map global resources in terraform provider

Tags: go, terraform

I'm writing a terraform provider for a software, which has a large set of instance specific global configurations (approximately 300 of them). When you use the provider, you define your endpoint and credentials and then operate within this instance. What I'm struggling to decide is how exactly to manage this config. It's not a resource that is created or destroyed, so I'm not sure if creating a `global_config` resource would be the best approach. Since all the values will already have been initialised during the setup of the system and can only be overridden; the config cannot be destroyed; you can't have more than two config resources. Since you should be able to override all entries, it can't be a data source either.

I haven't managed to find any relevant documentation (or even similar examples) so far, so I would be very grateful, if someone could point me to anything relevant, or suggest how to best achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: This question could use some more details, but this sounds like something that should be part of the provider schema.

Comment: @MattSchuchard -- what additional details should I add? 
I don't think adding it to the provider schema makes sense, as the user is supposed to be managing those configs via terraform and I don't think that's what the provider schema itself is intended for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform's provider model is designed primarily for objects that Terraform itself can create or destroy. There is no built-in support for automatically "adopting" an existing object to be under Terraform's management, because Terraform generally assumes that each object is managed by exactly one declared resource instance and Terraform aims to preserve that assumption by being the one to have created the object.

However, there are some existing examples in other systems of this sort of "singleton" object that is implicitly created but can have its settings changed. Key examples for study are the resource types for default VPCs and their default public subnets in AWS.

There are currently two broad ways to represent this situation in Terraform, neither of which is perfect and so each of which has some advantages and disadvantages to consider:

- **Mandatory `terraform import`**: you can potentially build your resource type so that its "create" action always immediately fails telling the user to import the existing object, and then to implement the "import" action to allow users to explicitly bind their existing object to their Terraform resource instance using the `terraform import` command.

  This is the more explicit of the two options in that it requires the user to *intentionally* declare that the existing object should be managed by this Terraform configuration, in the same way that users normally take that action in Terraform. This means that the user remains in control and can (as they must always do when importing) take care to import that object into only one resource instance in one Terraform configuration, thereby preserving Terraform's uniqueness assumption.

  However, it also adds a mandatory extra setup step to any Terraform configuration which uses this resource type. That extra step does not fit well into [typical automation around Terraform](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/automate-terraform), and so that step will often need to be taken in an exceptional way outside of a team's normal workflow.
- **Treat "create" as if it were "adopt"**: since the actions a provider is expected to implement for a resource type are just a matter convention, there's no *technical* reason that your "create" action cannot just verify that the configured object exists and return success without creating anything. I call that "adopting" here to represent the idea that Terraform will then assume that this existing object is now under the exclusive management of whatever resource instance claimed to have created it, but "adopting" is not actually a formal part of Terraform's workflow.

  This has the advantage of fitting well into an existing Terraform workflow, requiring no unusual additional steps on the part of the operator.

  However, it also means that it's easier to accidentally adopt the same object into two different resource instances, either in the same configuration or in separate configurations. The consequences of doing that will vary depending on what the object represents, but at minimum it will likely result in the different resource instances "fighting" one another, constantly undoing each other's work on each new Terraform run and thus never converging on a stable desired state.

The second of these is the more convenient of the two and so is the one that existing providers have typically chosen as long as the consequences of incorrect multiple-adoption are *just* the risk of a non-converging system: that situation is confusing and kinda annoying, but also often not super harmful.

The first is the safer of the two because it guards against the accidental multiple-adoption problem. It could be appropriate if two configurations fighting to control a single object may have more significant consequences, such as one configuration *breaking* the other one by changing its settings in a way that is invalid for the other use-case.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! I had already started implementing the "adopt" approach, but was wondering if there were better options. I agree that the import path can be a bit contra-intuitive, so will stick with the adopt option :)